# Use node short id module with angular 6 in typescript

Tags: node.js, angularjs, typescript, angular6

I tried to use the node module in an Angular 6 typescript.

first: npm i shortid

```
In TypeScript class:

import { shortid } from 'shortid';

let Uid = shortid.generate();
```

but i got an error "can not find function generate()";

how to use it correctly ?

Comment: you may need to `import * as shortid from 'shortid';` instead

Comment: @BlackICE thank you for your comment....!!! it has solved my problem...  really worked for me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of

```
import { shortid } from 'shortid';
```

do

```
import { generate } from 'shortid';
```

and execute the code with

```
let Uid = generate();
```

`shortid` doesn't come with TypeScript typings preinstalled, so you won't get information about what exactly you can import, arguments and return values within IDEs like Visual Studio Code.
You can fix this by installing typings for `shortid` - go to Microsoft's [TypeSearch](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/) website, enter "shortid" and you'll be redirected to the npm package [@types/shortid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/shortid), which you can install with `npm i @types/shortid`.
You can also check the [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) directly, where a lot of types for javascript packages are published.

After installing they typings, the IDE will show you information and offer auto completion for `shortid` similar to native typescript modules.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my trouble ...and thanks alot for your detail information which help me while facing other obstacles related to @TypeScript, and "You're welcome, glad I could help!